# How to deploy a NodeJS app without root access, so it stays online after server restarts?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, pm2, forever

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS app. I tried npm forever and pm2, but I believe that my hoster restarts the server every night because my app is always offline the next day.

The thing is, that I have a shared hosting server on A2hosting and don't have root access, so these `sudo` commands don't work here... except you know how I can change that, haha...

I don't know what infos I need to provide for you to help me... so if you need to know something, tell me please!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've used pm2 to do that.

```
npm install -g pm2
```

then you run the following command to ensure pm2 will run on startup:

```
pm2 startup
```

It will show you the command you have to run.

Finally, you initiate the process:

```
pm2 start server.js --name <service-name>
```

Freeze your process list:

```
pm2 save
```

More details on pm2 documentation: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: That won't work without root access as startup has to write to root owned directories to install an init script or service module.